# Laravel - Request::server('HTTP_HOST') returns 'localhost' from within a helper class

Tags: session, laravel-4, http-post-vars

I want to get the current domain, using Request::server('HTTP_HOST') - however when I call this from within a helper class it comes back as 'localhost' which is not what I want. From a controller it works as expected. Is there a way to access this information from within a helper class?

The helper class looks like this:

```
class ApiWrapper {
    public static function call($model, $method='', array $input) {



        $domain = Request::server('HTTP_HOST');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do `URL::to('/')` to get the base URL of the Laravel application, if that's what you're asking for. If doing `Request::server('HTTP_HOST')` from your controller is giving you the desired result, doing the same from the helper class shouldn't be any different.

Comment: Thanks however I still get 'localhost' from URL::to('/') from the helper class. Wonder if I need to include anything in the helper so it can access those session variables?

Comment: @Adamski having the same issue. Did you find a fix?

Comment: @AakilFernandes sorry I don't think I did - that project was abandoned, and looking at the code I still had the URL hard-coded.

Comment: @Adamski. No worries. I ended up just using environment switches and hardcoding. Not a great fix but I suppose it works for now.